# how to duplicate one line of code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I worked by Visual Studio and i want to know how can I duplicate a line in my source code in Android Studio IDE ?

i tried `shift`+'alt'+`down' but it didnt work :/

Comment: IntelliJ, upon which Android Studio is based, uses CTRL+D.

Comment: yes i found how to do ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found that I can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. So cool.

Also you can move a line of code down and up by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up/down</kbd>.

On mac systems press <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

On mac, you can do
`command + d` and this will do the same functionality of vs code's `shift + alt + down arrow`

Answer (score 1):

On Mac:

Duplicate line or selection: **⌘ + D**

If you select a few lines then all these lines will be duplicated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For someone is looking for it at 2022, use `option + command + arrow down` on Mac (M1, at least for me)